# Using PHP, how do I echo a line from a text file that starts with a specific value?

Tags: php

Lets say the text file " data1.txt" contains:

```
56715||Jim||Green||19  
5678||Sara||Red||92    
53676||Mark||Orange||6  
56787||Mike||Purple||123  
56479||Sammy||Yellow||645  
56580||Martha||Blue||952
ect...
.
.
```

I would like to echo only the line beginning with "5678||". "5678" is the exact $refVal or reference value. The line should display like this:

```
My name is: $nameVar
My color is: $colorVar
My number is: $numVar
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$fh = fopen('data1.txt', 'r') or die('Unable to open data1.txt');
while($line = fgetcsv($fh, 0, '||')) {
   if ($line[0] == 5678) {
       echo <<<EOL
My name is: $line[1]
My color is $line[2]
My number is $line[3]
EOL;
       break; // if there's only ever one '5678' line in the, get out now.
   }
}
fclose($fh);
```

---

alternate version, as suggested by Jared below. Probably will be faster, as it only does the array creation on the line that actually matches, and not for each line as the fgetcsv version does.

```
$fh = fopen('data1.txt', 'r') or die('Unable to open data1.txt');
while($line = fgets($fh)) {
   if (strpos($line, '5678||') === 0) { // only if right at start of string
        $data = explode('||', $line);
        echo <<<EOL
my name is blah blah blah 
EOL;
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of a substring after reading the file into a variable, but this will probably be more progressive with memory use, right?

Comment: substring would be much "lighter" than the fgetcsv, but you've got variable length numberstrings, so you'd have to be very careful on how much you extract. if you're looking for a 4digit '5678', you could quite easily "match" 56787.

Comment: I think this will use less memory all at once (possibly a good thing if the file is large), but is also probably harder on the disk (lots of little reads, rather than one big read as you'd get if you did `$lines = file('data1.txt');` to read the whole file into an array all at once).

Comment: And I was thinking the read-all-into-memory part would probably be the less efficient part to `fgetcsv()` reading a line at a time.

Comment: @Jared. good point. `if (strpos($line, '5678||') === 0) { explode/echo }` would work nicely.

Comment: @Marc B On alternate example, I get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL in /www/tests/display_line_test/index.php on line 14

Comment: @mobilestimulus: That usually means you've got spaces after `echo <<<EOL`. There shoulbe nothing after the `L`, just a linebreak. I see I forgot to put in the EOL bit in my alternate version. I'll fix up the answer (and those are called [heredocs](http://php.net/heredoc), by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can split each line into an array using `explode`, like so:

```
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $t = explode('||', $line);

    if ($t[0] == $refVal) {
        // echo the rest of $t array however you want
        // $t[1] would be the name, $t[2] the color, etc    
    }
}
```